# Text matching: fuzzy names matching with learning

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-understanding

I'm new to AI/ML and I want to research and learn about techniques that could help me to solve this complex task. Any hint would be appreciated.

Let me explain it with an example:

Let's look at two columns `PUR.SUPPLY.MTL_REQ_HDR_ID` and `MTL.PO_REQUISITION_HEADERS_TAB.ID`. It is likely they are related (one is the FK and the other one is PK).

[image]

As a human I was able to do it by doing the following:

1. I decoded abbreviations,
2. I identified context (MTL module),
3. I identified the subject (requisition header),
4. I identified ID keyword,
5. I identified irrelevant information (TAB postfix),
6. I matched words that are not in the exact order,
7. I estimated which elements/words do not have to match/occur,

I would like to match millions of columns relatively quickly (seconds). I would like algorithm to learn:

1. what words are likely context,
2. what are irrelevant,
3. what are subjects,
4. ideally learn some patterns (prefixes, postfixes, name formats, etc),
5. based on user responses - approve/reject match,
6. build dictionary of abbreviations,
7. estimate probability...

I know this is a complex task, but maybe you know a technique, tool, library, article, example ... anything that could be helpful? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In general Bayesian networks/Naive Bayes do well at text processing. As a library sci-kit has an implementation.

Comment: Thanks @A_Arnold, Naive Bayes seems to be a classification function. I don't think my problem is a classificaiton problem.

Comment: If you already have some of these matches you can try and scale it to new data. i.e. your pk & fk cols would be x1, x2, match would be y1=1 no match y1=0. Do this for some data, then let it predict some data, update that data if the classification is wrong etc. ALT: you may want to look into ICA which can predict topics. https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/papers/isbell-ica-nips-1999.pdf

Comment: thanks @A_Arnold. We will need to test the bayes and research the ICA. That might be a good start.